# How to update packages after upgrading Django?

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm using Django 1.8.4 and currently in the process of upgrading it to 1.11.1

I have many packages and dependencies installed inside a virtual environment, and I'm not sure how should I check/update them.

How can I easily check what should be updated?

How can I check which packages are not supported yet with the latest Django?

Should I do it manually or is there a tool that helps handle large number of packages?

Thanks,

Comment: why dont you upgrade the version of django and try to run the project? as i think django version will not be a prblem

Comment: I did it, and then came across packages that uses removed features and need to be updated. Since I have many packages, I wanted to check if there is a convenient method regarding how to update them

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Thank you, but it's ok. I can handle the errors and check the documentation regarding what packages should be updated and how. I was just looking for a way or a tool to handle multiple packages, i.e- what packages should be updated, what is not supported, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are no hard and fast rules except to create a new virtualenv and try it out. You can install the latest versions of everything in your old virtualenv in the new one as as follows

```
source old/activate
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  > requirements.txt
deactivate
source new/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks!
I ended up running our test and update the packages manually, as we didn;t want to update everything to the latest at once.

Comment: Just to be clear, in 2019 there's no equivalent to 'yum check-update'?

Comment: this has nothing to do with yum